# Dynamic query string in route

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to accept anything in the query string of a route in .NET Core API 2.X? For example, if I were to pass the following to the same action, but with different query strings, I would receive a response containing the query string.

- `localhost:PORT/api/values/echo?something=2&somethingelse=test`
- `localhost:PORT/api/values/echo?word=hello-world`

The response to the two requests would respectively be:

- `something=2&somethingelse=test`
- `word=hello-world`

I thought the attempt below would work, but I was mistaken.

```cs
        [HttpGet("echo")]
        public IActionResult Echo(dynamic query)
        {
            return Ok(query);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [HttpGet("echo")]
    public IActionResult Echo()
    {
        var query = Request.QueryString.ToString();
        return Ok(query);
    }
```

This is for you case. But generally I don't see any point in it, you may want to use a class instead.

Comment: So I'd use a parameterless action. I imagined there'd be an Action filter attribute or a model binder or something.